# Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:

Tags: laravel

http://themovingpixel.com/myfinancialgoals/email

I have error on my site to send email. I search on stackoverflow and get answers but none of that work for me.

my .evn file code

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***********************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=''
```

my routes.php code

```
Route::get('/email', function()
{
Mail::send('email.test', [], function ($message)
{
    $message->to('orijit14@gmail.com', 'HisName')->subject('Welcome!');
});
});
```

My email.blade.php code

```
<?php echo "hii"; ?>
```

Comment: Your actual mail config file is `config/mail.php`. Despite the fact that usage of `.env` file is encouraged, your `config/mail.php` file can override those configuration variables. Check your `config/mail.php`  and see if that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. My problem was solved by editing the .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mywebsite.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***********************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=''
```